# How to use Bluetooth, SPI and UART at the same time with an RPI3?

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, screen, spi, uart

I just bought a `Rpi3` and a `Kuman 3.5"` screen to make a minimal computer.
I also have a `PN532` to do NFC.

My configuration:
- `Kuman 3.5` screen is connected to `SPI0.0`, touchscreen to `SPI0.1`;
- I need on-board Bluetooth for my PS3 keyboard, I paid for it :)

The problems with Electrohouse V2.0 PN532 are:
 - The chip won't works with SPI1.0 (`error   libnfc.driver.pn532_spi Unable to wait for SPI data. (RX)`);
 - UART is used by Bluetooth;
 - And I want to keep i2c for something else.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of reading and testing I found how to do it.

Three lines are needed to the `/boot/config.txt` to make it works.

```
#Switch Bluetooth from UART0 to UART1.
dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
#UART1 clock is derived from system clock, so we need to fix core clock to avoid changing baudrate on bluetooth.
core_freq=250
#Set UART0 clock to normal as Rpi3 normally boot at 400Mhz (now 250Mhz) UART0 clock would biased else.
init_uart_clock=3000000
```

So let sum up:
 - On-board Bluetooth works flawlessly with my PS3 BT Keyboard;
 - Screen and touchscreen still works, hopefully;
 - PN532 works like a charm using UART0 (Pin 8 & 10)

Sources:
https://www.slideshare.net/yeokm1/raspberry-pi-3-uartbluetooth-issues
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.1.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/README
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=138223
https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/800